# least square estimation in python using numpy and scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, least-squares

Both scipy and numpy has least square estimation but I got slightly confused after reading the documentation.

So, my problem is classical regression where I am trying to find the best matrix transformation between two pairs of values. So something of the form:

```
Ax = b
```

Here, I know x and b. A has 9 unique components and x and b are 3D vectors. So, I need at least 3 points. So, 3 non-collinear x and b and I have them and I can create a 3x3 concatenated x and b vectors.

However, from the documentation, I see that it is designed for solving systems when A and b are known. So we solve for x. Assuming A is invertible, this would mean something like:

```
x = A(-1)b          (-1) indicating the inverse or pseudo inverse.
```

In my case, the solution becomes

```
A = b x(-1)
```

I was wondering if I can still somehow use the built in numpy machinery for my setup.

Comment: The pseudo inverse of a vector x is the matrix inv(t(x)*x)*t(x) where t(x) is x transposed and * is matrix product.    All of that can be done in python. There's also functions like [numpy.linalg.lstsq()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq) and modules like StatsModel. There's also other stack overflow Q&A on this topic in python... chances that this is a duplicate question are pretty high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this:

```
Ax = b
x^TA^T = b^T
```

where `A^T` indicates the transpose of `A`. Now define the symbols `Ap=x^T` and `Xp = A^T` and `bp=b^T` and your problem becomes:

```
Ap Xp = bp
```

that is exactly in the form that you can treat with least squares